# How do I add resistance to a ball joint?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to make a simple design that consists of two ball joints connected to each other in such a way that I have rotation and translation of the second joint, but with an adjustable resistance. I'm no engineer, so I'm unsure about the whole thing, and I might end up using different types of mechanical joints altogether. How can I add resistance to a ball joint? Is there any well-known two joint structure that resembles what I want?

Comment: two ball joints tend to be overkill.  consider what freedoms you actually need.  selective arrangements can grant benefits- for example SCARA robotic arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ball joint can be seated in a split-spherical shell socket that is tightened by screw. The one below uses a hydraulic mechanism to tighten all the clamps present with a single knob, but other models use a wire. Of course a direct bolt could also be used per joint.

Most obviously seen in the photo on the "wrist joint" and the "shoulder joint". It's dark, but look closely, you can see the split in the spherical shell that allows how tightly it clamps the ball to be adjusted.

Actually thinking about it, it might actually draw the ball into a wedge shaped groove to exert clamping pressure rather than closing the spherical half-shell around the ball.

[image]
Mitutoyo 7033B

Comment: yep. see also: [Swivel Link](https://swivellink.com/) ... they have ones with like 4x 3-DOF joints in a chain that you can lock all of them at the same time with a single turn of a single knob

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of adjustable ball joints available to connect to truck trailers or small trailers towed by a car.

But they adjust for height and extension, not resistance because that would defy their function which is a strong but flexible connection.

I recommend you consider an adjustable grip mechanism like that of an adjustable arm tabletop light. They have adjustable grip joints.

'

[image]